# C# Telegram Bot Notification

Tags: c#, bots, telegram

Is there a way in C# to send a notification to a user (personal message) from a bot? I only found solutions to send messages to a channel/group where my bot is added with Admin rights.

I want to send notifications - if allowed - from my system to the user when logged in / system notifications.

Later on I want to enable the user to send commands to this bot to action some key functionalities in the system - such as, but not limited to, adding new users. With the necessary administrator rights of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this answer as I solved my own question after several hours of researching and testing.

First off, I created a EventHandler class to handle all incoming messages to my Telegram bot:

```
    public class TelegramBotEvents
    {
        private readonly TelegramBotClient _telegramBotClient;
        private readonly ODWorkflowDBContext _context;

        public TelegramBotEvents(
            ODWorkflowDBContext context,
            TelegramBotClient telegramBotClient
        )
        {
            this._context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

            this._telegramBotClient = telegramBotClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(telegramBotClient));

#pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete. TODO: Implement Polling
            this._telegramBotClient.StartReceiving();
            this._telegramBotClient.OnMessage += (sender, eventArg) =>
            {
                if (eventArg.Message != null)
                {
                    MessageReceive(eventArg.Message);
                }
            };
#pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete. TODO: Implement Polling
        }

        public void MessageReceive(Message message)
        {
            try
            {
                if (message.Type == MessageType.Text)
                {
                    if (message.Text.ToLower() == "/register")
                    {
                        var userThirdPartyNotification = this._context.UserThirdPartyNotifications.FirstOrDefault(e =>
                            e.UserThirdPartyNotificationActive &&
                            e.UserThirdPartyNotificationUserName == message.From.Username);

                        userThirdPartyNotification.UserThirdPartyNotificationChatId = message.From.Id;

                        this._context.UserThirdPartyNotifications.Update(userThirdPartyNotification);
                        this._context.SaveChanges();

                        this._telegramBotClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.From.Id, "You have successfully opted in to receive notifications via Telegram.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this._telegramBotClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.From.Id, $"\"{message.Text}\" was not found. Please try again.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this._telegramBotClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.From.Id, $"Failure processing your message: {ex.Message}");
            }

        }
    }
```

After the above I Injected this class in my Startup:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSession();

            #region Dependency_Injections
            services.AddScoped<IPasswordEncrypt, PasswordEncrypt>();
            services.AddScoped<IHelperFunctions, HelperFunctions>();
            services.AddScoped<IEncryptor, Encryptor>();
            services.AddTransient(typeof(ILogging<>), typeof(Logging<>));

            services.AddSingleton(new TelegramBotClient(Configuration["ArtificialConfigs:TelegramBotToken"]));

            services.AddScoped(p => 
                new TelegramBotEvents(
                    (DBContext)p.GetService(typeof(DBContext)), 
                    (TelegramBotClient)p.GetService(typeof(TelegramBotClient))));
            #endregion

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }
```

After these two steps I could capture the client id from the user that sent any message to my bot.

Once any user logins - with permissions granted inside the web system - they will receive personal messages from my bot inside Telegram.